Are there any open source Chess GUI?
I'm looking for UCI-compatible chess GUI source code or documentation to dive deeper into its functionalities. I was particularly interested in the Arena source code but came up empty-handed in my search.

Where did you look? There's over 1900 results on github for chess gui.

Yes, many. Take a look at cutechess

Here are some open source GUI's that I know of:
ChessX
https://sourceforge.net/projects/chessx/
Lucas chess
https://sourceforge.net/projects/lucaschessr/
SCID
https://sourceforge.net/projects/scid/
ChessForge
https://sourceforge.net/projects/chessforge/
cutechess
https://github.com/cutechess/cutechess
just a few to check

I would recommend SCID, which is a state-of-the-art GUI for chess analysis. It is UCI-compatible, and can be used to load and manage different databases related to chess as well.
Here's the link to the repository for your exploration.
